# Elastic search highlight not working

Tags: elasticsearch, highlighting

I am new to elastic search and i am trying to highlight the matched keywords

```
GET /{index}/_search 
{
  "query": {
     "match": {
     "_all": "first"
     }
   },
  "highlight": { 
     "fields": { 
         "*": {} 
       },
     "require_field_match": false
   } 
}
```

My output is a nested object.I also tried without "require_field_match" parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the 2 methods mentioned in below link to search and highlight on all fields

> A field can only be used for highlighting if the original string value
>   is available, either from the _source field or as a stored field.
>
> The _all field is not present in the _source field and it is not
>   stored or enabled by default, and so cannot be highlighted. There are
>   two options. Either store the _all field or highlight the original
>   fields.

[Highlight all fields](http://nocf-www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#highlighting-all-field)

Answer (score -1):

you can't produce a highlight with a search from the `_all` field.

You have to search in an actual field for it to work:

```
GET /{index}/_search 
{
  "query": {
     "match": {
       "title": "first"
     }
   },
  "highlight": { 
     "fields": { 
         "title": {} 
     }
   } 
}
```

Comment: But I need to search across almost all fields